# Why did the Marathas plan to crown the Peshwa's son as the Emperor but not the Peshwa himself?

Tags: india

The Marathas wanted to depose the Mughal Emperor during the Maratha-Afghan war (the 3rd battle of Panipat) and crown Viswasrao (the son of the Peshwa Balaji Bajirao Nanasahib) as the Emperor.

I got this information from the book "[Islamic Renaissance In South Asia (1707-1867) : The Role Of Shah Waliallah" by M.A. Ghazi](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=QO4KjzuJ52QC&q=vishwasrao%20peshwa%20throne%20delhi&pg=PA130&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=vishwasrao%20peshwa%20throne%20delhi&f=false) , where it says :

> "Some maratha chiefs tried to place a young lad of seventeen, Vishwas Rao, the son of the Peshwa, on the throne of Delhi to proclaim the realization of their long cherished dream of Hindu pad padshahi"

The same information has been used in [Viswasrao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishwasrao), [Marathe Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maratha_Empire) etc

If it is true, then why would the Marathas want to crown their leader's son instead of crowning the leader himself? Also, if they succeeded, what would their administration look like — where the Peshwa's son would act as superior to the Peshwa himself?

Comment: I read it in wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishwasrao#:~:text=Vishwasrao%20was%20the%20leader%20of,the%20most%20intense%20fighting%20(Approx.  and also in some other sources, I am adding those links too. It might be a rumor as the plan was never executed- but still a strange kind of rumor

Comment: Please edit your question to include the quotation you refer to and also add a citation for your source.

Comment: added the citation

Comment: The usual reason for this sort of thing is that a young king is easier to manipulate than an older one.

Comment: yes, but the Marathas  already had an older king (Peshwa was more like hereditary prime-minister to be precise- but acted like a king). In that case, why would they crown his son as the Emperor of the conquered territories, whereas he was alive?

Comment: It is like Charlemagne's son is crowned as the Holy Roman Emperor, whereas he himself lives as the King of the Franks !

Comment: Sometimes these arranements are done to prevent a single individual holding too much power. It was not that uncommon in Europe for arrangements preventing too many titles (especially royalty) in the same person. For example, after the War of Spanish Succession, the Kingdom of Naples was ruled by Borbons, but it could not have the same King as Spain. Charles III of Spain was originally King of Naples, but when his older brother died and he became King of Spain he had to relinquish the Neapolitan title.

Comment: @SJuan76 That might be the case. The maratha army was being led by the Peshwa's cousin along-with other maratha lords and some of their non-maratha vassals. Many of them might have been against the increasing power of the Peshwa. Specially, the northern maratha lords already possessed some political  control over Delhi even before the formal attack ordered by the Peshwa's cousin. So, the plan of crowning the Peshwa's son as the Emperor in Delhi might be a compromise- so that they could exert control over the new Emperor and could also make the Peshwa happy.